# How to use if else in SQL and VBA together

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code below will search the table and extract results based on filters that are hard coded. I have set the default dates above 2014 and until current.  But what should I do, if I a user passes date ranges and location(Credited Office) dynamically and wants the results the results within those date range and location. In case, if the user doesn't enters any dates, the code should default to specific dates from 2014 to 3012 and show for all regions.

```
SELECT a.[RDT_FileID]
    , a.[Master Policy Number]
    , a.[Work item /Submission no#]
    , a.[Insured Name]
    , a.[Issuing Office]
    , a.[Issuing Underwriter]
    , a.[Product Line]
    , a.[Product Line Subtype]
    , a.[Current Status]
    , a.[Effective Date]
    , a.[Expiry Date]
FROM DB1.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a
WHERE a.[Master Policy Number] IS NOT NULL
    AND a.[Current Status] = 'Bound'
    AND a.[RDT_FileID] IS NULL
    AND a.[Product Line Subtype] <> '0102-Marine'
    AND a.[Effective Date] >= '2014-04-01'
```

Comment: Please include the full definition of your table so answerers can see what indexes and constraints you created.

Comment: How fast does it execute if you do Select a.* from .... a where a.[current status] = 'Bound'?

Comment: What does your execution plan look like?

Comment: `View_Property_Rater_Of_Record` Is this a `View` ?

Comment: If you are benchmarking performance you might want to ADD A WITH RECOMPILE OPTION to your statement so that the optimizer will always generate a new query plan, instead of pulling one from the plan cache.

Comment: @prdp Yeah.. It's a VIEW

Comment: @Shasti - Show the view definition

Comment: @user1628733 I tried executing the entire statement commenting the current status. It takes 0 seconds. But When I execute just the current status it takes 23 seconds

Comment: Would you try to make a `case` statement? `case when a.[Current Status] = 'Bound' then 1 end as [Current Status] ` and then change to `AND a.[Current Status] not null`

Comment: @aFast If you dont mind can you post it as answer. I am not sure how to use "and" along with case, because I have multiple filter conditions that needs to applied along with current status

Comment: @Shasti Posted let me know if it worked please

Comment: @Shasti - we need the table and view definition.

Comment: This could be several things, like statistics being off, cardinality estimation problem, parameter sniffing... You should include the view & table & index definitions and query plans when it works fast and when it doesn't. Otherwise we're just guessing here.

Comment: If you just want to prevent SQL server from searching with `a.[Current Status] = 'Bound'` you could try to prevent index usage with kludge with something like `nullif(a.[Current Status],NULL) = 'Bound'` -- that at least used to work.

Comment: Just a thought: make sure that a.[Current Status] is not a Unicode column (nvarchar). If it is then compare with N'Bound' to avoid conversion penalty on all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT a.[RDT_FileID]
        , a.[Master Policy Number]
        , a.[Work item /Submission no#]
        , a.[Insured Name]
        , a.[Issuing Office]
        , a.[Issuing Underwriter]
        , a.[Product Line]
        , a.[Product Line Subtype]
        , a.[Current Status]
        , case when a.[Current Status] = 'Bound' then 1 end as [SomeName]
        , a.[Effective Date]
        , a.[Expiry Date]
    FROM DB1.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a
    WHERE a.[Master Policy Number] IS NOT NULL
        --AND a.[Current Status] = 'Bound'
        AND a.[RDT_FileID] IS NULL
        AND a.[Product Line Subtype] <> '0102-Marine'
        AND a.[Effective Date] >= '2014-04-01')T1
WHERE [SomeName] IS NOT NULL
```